# Unable to get user location when hosting in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am creating a website in asp.net version 4.0. I am able to get the device location using GeoCoordinateWatcher class when i host it using local asp.net development server. But wen i host it in IIS, I get GeoCoordinateWatcher.permission as denied and GeoCoordinateWatcher.status as disabled.
Please help.

**UPDATE**

```
int count = 0; 
coodi: gcw.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)); 
GeoCoordinate cood; 
var y = gcw.Status; 
if (y != GeoPositionStatus.Ready && count<6) { 
    count++; goto coodi; 
} 
cood = gcw.Position.Location; 
if (cood.IsUnknown != true) { 
    lat = cood.Latitude; 
    lon = cood.Longitude; 
    count = 0; 
} else { 
    lat = lon = -1; 
}
```

Could anyone help me to request the user to allow me to use his location as any site requests like, "This site wants to use your location? Allow or deny?".

Comment: Please show example code

Comment: Also, check [ask] for how to get the most out of your questions.

Comment: int count = 0;
        coodi:
            gcw.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
            GeoCoordinate cood;
            var y = gcw.Status;
            if (y != GeoPositionStatus.Ready && count<6)
            {
                count++;
                goto coodi;
            }
            cood = gcw.Position.Location;
            if (cood.IsUnknown != true)
            {
                lat = cood.Latitude;
                lon = cood.Longitude;
                count = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                lat = lon = -1;
            }

Answer (score 0):

The API you're looking for is the HTML5 Geolocation API: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

You can't use local APIs like System.Device.Location from serverside script to get the remote client's location.

Comment: I tried doing this from the .cs file by creating a script and calling it using Response.Write method. It works but I am not able to get the coordinate values back on the server side.
Please suggest.